# Creating a time series plot and converting numeric data to date

Tags: r

I want to create a plot of time per temperature in 2 sites. I have data of the temperature each 10 minutes a day from february to april and I need daily cycles of hourly averages of temperature to plot.

I calculated the mean temperature for hour a day and try to create a plot with geom_plot and geopm_line of different ways.

```
data <- read.xlsx("temperatura.xlsx", 1)
data <- data %>% mutate (month = as.factor(month), month = as.factor (month), day = as.factor(day), h = as.factor(h), min = as.factor(min))

head (data)
month day h min  t.site1 t.site2
  2   1   0   0  15.485  16.773
  2   1   0  10  15.509  16.773
  2   1   0  20  15.557  16.773
  2   1   0  30  15.557  16.773
  2   1   0  40  15.605  16.773
  2   1   0  50  15.605  16.773


str(data)
'data.frame':   12816 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ month  : Factor w/ 3 levels "2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day    : Factor w/ 31 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ h      : Factor w/ 24 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ min    : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","10","20",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ t.site1: num  15.5 15.5 15.6 15.6 15.6 ...
 $ t.site2: num  16.8 16.8 16.8 16.8 16.8 ...


hour <- group_by(data, month, day, h) 

mean.h.site1 <- summarize(hour, mean.h.site1 = mean(t.site1))

t1 <- ggplot (data = mean.h.site1, aes(x=h, y=mean.h.site1)) +
  geom_line()

t2 <- ggplot(data = mean.h.site1, aes(x=h, y=mean.h.site1, group = month))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()

t3 <- ggplot (data = mean.h.site1, aes(x=day, y=mean.h.site1, group=1))+
  geom_point()
```

I expect the output of the variability of temperature across the time for each site, but the actual output show temperature variability during each day.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that your data is showing month, day and hour as `factor`. Is it possible that there are some character values somewhere in that column when you read the data? It's very unusual to see numbers stored as factor in that fashion.

I'll do 4 things:

1. Convert factors to numbers
2. Convert numbers to dates
3. Convert a wide table to a long one, and finally
4. plot the temps against a real date

   ```
   # Load packages and data
   library(data.table) # for overall fast data processing
   library(lubridate) # for dates wrangling
   library(ggplot2) # plotting

   dt <- fread("month day h min  t.site1 t.site2
     2   1   0   0  15.485  16.773
     2   1   0  10  15.509  16.773
     2   1   0  20  15.557  16.773
     2   1   0  30  15.557  16.773
     2   1   0  40  15.605  16.773
     2   1   0  50  15.605  16.773")

   # Convert factors to numbers (I actuall didn't run this because I just created the data.table, but it seems you'll need to do it):

   dt[, names(dt)[1:4] := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)), .SDcols = 1:4]

   # Create proper dates. We'll consider all dates occurring in 2019.
   dt[, date := ymd_hm(paste0("2019/", month, "/", day, " ", h, ":", min))]

   # convert wide data to long one
   dt2 <- melt(dt[, .(date, t.site1, t.site2)], id.vars = "date")

   # plot the data
   ggplot(dt2, aes(x = date, y = value, color = variable))+geom_point()+geom_path()
   ```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Nice answer, may I suggest that you add data at the very bottom, that would make it even more concise.

Comment: Good advice, I'll take it as a style guide. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions you are very didatic. I change the value scale of date, because in your plot showed values for each 10 minutes, and I need values of mean temperature per hour.

Comment: I have received a lot from the stack overflow community, I'm happy to help and give back a little of what I have received

Comment: If you consider the answer as helpful, you may tick the check mark next to it, indicating it's an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you needed the actual output showing temperature variability by hour for each day in the same plot?

EDITED:
I have updated the code to generate a day worth of data. And, also generate the chart.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(month = rep(2, 144), 
                 day = rep(1, 144),
                 h = rep(0:24, each = 6, len = 144),
                 min = rep((0:5)*10,24),
                 t.site1 = rnorm(n = 144, mean = 15.501, sd = 0.552),
                 t.site2 = rnorm(n = 144, mean = 16.501, sd = 0.532))

df %>%
        group_by(month, day, h) %>%
        summarise(mean_t_site1 = mean(t.site1), mean_t_site2 = mean(t.site2)) %>%
        mutate(date = ymd_h(paste0("2019-",month,"-",day," ",h))) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        select(mean_t_site1:date) %>%
        gather(key = "site", value = "mean_temperature", -date) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = date, y = mean_temperature, colour = site)) +
        geom_line()
```

Could you verify if this is the output you need?
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ho, but in your suggestion it didn't calculate the mean temperature for each hour a day. And the lines will be the site 1 and site 2. I need that x=hour inside a day and month.

Comment: You needed a time-series on the x-axis that shows hours/day/month.. and mean termperature for site 1 and site 2? I think the answer that @pavodive is correct.

Comment: @Monique I have updated the code and the plot. Is that what you needed now?

Comment: thanks to help me. It is exactly what I looking for! I just change your code ´mutate(date = ymd_h(paste0("2019-",month,"-",day," ",h)))´ for `mutate(date = ymd_h(paste0("2019/",month,"/",day," ",h, ":")))` because showed the message: **Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found**

Answer (score 0):

You could paste the time columns together and convert them `as.POSIXct`.

As *@PavoDive* already pointed out we'll need numeric time columns. Check your code that produced the data or transform to numeric with `d[1:4] <- Map(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)), d[1:4])`.

Now `paste` the rows with `apply`, convert `as.POSIXct`, and `cbind` it to the remainder. The `sprintf` looks first that all values have the same digits before pasting.

```
d2 <- cbind(time=as.POSIXct(apply(sapply(d[1:4], sprintf, fmt="%02d"), 1, paste, collapse=""), 
                  format="%m%d%H%M"), 
            d[5:6])
```

Plots nicely, here in base R:

```
with(d2, plot(time, t.site1, ylim=c(15, 17), xaxt="n",
              xlab="time", ylab="value", type="b", col="red",
              main="Time series"))
with(d2, lines(time, t.site2, type="b", col="green"))
mtext(strftime(d2$time, "%H:%M"), 1, 1, at=d2$time)  # strftime gives the desired formatting
legend("bottomright", names(d2)[2:3], col=c("red", "green"), lty=rep(1, 2))
```

[image]

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2", class = "factor"), 
    day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    h = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
    min = structure(1:6, .Label = c("0", "10", "20", "30", "40", 
    "50"), class = "factor"), t.site1 = c(15.485, 15.509, 15.557, 
    15.557, 15.605, 15.605), t.site2 = c(16.773, 16.773, 16.773, 
    16.773, 16.773, 16.773)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```